# Uncountable dense subset whose complement is also uncountable and dense

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Locally non-enumerable dense subsets of R](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/35748/locally-non-enumerable-dense-subsets-of-r)

This may be a standard result... I don't know... anyway...

Does there exists an uncountable dense subset of $\mathbb{R}$ whose complement is also uncountable and dense?

Comment: This is much like http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/35748/locally-non-enumerable-dense-subsets-of-r/35750#35750. As the asker there notes, you can take the rationals $<0$ and the irrationals $>0$ as one set, and its complement as the other.

Comment: A similar problem that I find really fascinating is to find a dense set (in $\mathbb{R}$) of rational numbers whose compliment in the rationals is still dense, i.e. a partition of the rationals into two sets, both of which are dense.

Comment: @Matt: I think the set of dyadic rationals works.

Comment: The dyadic rationals (numbers that can be expressed as an integer divided by a nonnegative power of 2) and the remaining rationals are each dense in the reals and pairwise disjoint. By considering an analogous decomposition into all possible "prime-adic" rationals and the remaining rationals, you can get infinitely many pairwise disjoint sets of rationals, each of which is dense in the reals. Interestingly, if we weaken "pairwise disjoint" to "pairwise finite intersection", it's possible to get uncountably many dense sets of rationals.

Comment: My favorite example is fairly obscure. If $\sigma(n)$ is the sum of divisors of $n$, then the set of rational numbers of the form $\sigma(n)/n$ is dense, and the set of rationals not of that form is also dense! (This is sometimes called the "abundancy index" of an integer). Oops. I guess strictly speaking this is not true, they are only dense in $(-\infty, -1]\cup [1, \infty)$, still kind of weird though.

Comment: Are Bernstein sets dense in $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @tomcuchta: Yes, because a Bernstein set must meet every closed interval that are not singletons.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Funny, I asked myself the same question at one point! This should work:

$$A:=((-\infty,0]\cap\mathbb{Q})\cup ((0,+\infty)\cap(\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q})),$$
$$B:=((-\infty,0]\cap(\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}))\cup ((0,+\infty)\cap\mathbb{Q}) $$
They are both uncountable and dense, and form a partition of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: It doesn't get much simpler than that! (Note that intersecting $(-\infty,0]$ with $\mathbb{R}$ is a bit redundant.)

Comment: thanks, I'll correct that, I forgot to put parantheses...

Comment: It's even simpler to write $(-\infty,0] \setminus \mathbb{Q}$...

Comment: Absolutely, but I prefer the above notation.

Comment: As I commented at another (now deleted?) answer, these can be nicely written as $A = (0, \infty) \vartriangle \mathbb Q$ and  $B = \mathbb R \setminus A = (-\infty, 0] \vartriangle \mathbb Q$, where $\vartriangle$ is symmetric set difference.

Answer (score 6):

Take any uncountable set $A_0$ with measure $0$, e.g., the Cantor set. Let $$A = \bigcup_{q \in \mathbb{Q}} (A_0 + q) = \{a + q : a \in A_0, q \in \mathbb{Q}\}.$$
Then $A$ is uncountable, dense and it still has measure $0$ since it is the union of countably many translates of $A_0$. Since the complement of a measure $0$ set is always uncountable and dense, this set $A$ fits the bill.

Answer (score 1):

Probably not the best approach, but you can also try this: Let $B$ be a basis of $\mathbb R$ over $\mathbb Q$. Write $B=B_1 \cup B_2$ with $B_1 \cap B_2 =\emptyset$ and $B_1, B_2$ of the same cardinality.

Then $V= span_{\mathbb Q} B_1$ will do it. It is uncountable and dense ($B_1$ in uncountable, thus it contains two elements with irrational ration) and $\mathbb R \backslash V$ contains $W= span_{\mathbb Q} B_2$.

---

**Added a Second example**

Here is another example:

$$A:= \{ x=m.x_1x_2...x_n...| 0.x_2x_4x_6... {\rm \, is \, periodic \,} \}\,.$$

More exactly, $A$ consists of all those real numbers for which, the digits after $.$ of even order form a periodic sequence....

Comment: The only drawback is that you need some Axiom of Choice to get a basis for $\mathbb{R}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$...

Comment: True... And I am pretty sure one also needs the Axiom of choice to split $B$ that way...