# Subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ with the same Lebesgue measure on any open set

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, real-numbers

I'm looking for two sets in $\mathbb{R}$ which are both uncountable and dense, and where one is the complement of the other. I know the question has already been asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/35748/locally-non-enumerable-dense-subsets-of-r), but the solutions still didn't feel quite right to me: the sets didn't feel "even" enough in $\mathbb{R}$. So I realized what the question was that I really wanted answered.

*Are there two Lebesgue measurable subsets of $\mathbb{R}$, one of which is the complement of the other, which have the same Lebesgue measure on any open bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}$?*

The density of each set in $\mathbb{R}$ is as well as their uncountability is obvious, and the sets feel "even" everywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it turns out, a variant of this question has already been answered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1163417/subset-a-subset-mathbb-r-such-that-for-any-interval-i-of-length-a-the-set): the answer is no. :(

Still, I noticed that this is only for Lebesgue measure. Are there any other types of measure where this is possible?

Comment: I think you need some restrictions for the measure, obviously taking the trivial measure giving 0 everywhere together with the first answer gives an example. (or take too poor sigma algebra like the trivial and assign measure 1 to everything and masure 0 for the empty set)

Comment: Yeah, that's a good point. I think the question I referenced in this answer is probably a better formulation: that the measure is equal to half the length of the interval.